# How to implement autocomplete search box with image and the text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to implement a search box in my website with autocompleting text together with the photo.

Here's my current code:

**HTML**:

```html
<h4>search:<input type="text" id="name-list" /></h4>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#name-list").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Searchuser",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    searchText: request.term,
                    maxResults: 10
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.DisplayName + " R:" + item.Reputation,
                            value: item.DisplayName,
                            id: item.Id
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.id) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2, and I'm passing the json string (after querying the local db) with image url and other information from the controller to the view. Text is working fine.

Can anybody help me how to render image and append to the list item?

Comment: The `ui` object has two properties, which are both defined at the time of source creation, `ui.item.label`, and `ui.item.value`. The only way you could achieve this without movnig outside of the scope of the autocomplete -- or making an ajax call, is to use the SRC as the `ui.item.value`. Then you could use the `ui.item.value` as the `src` in `some image` you want to display. I'm drunk on SO from the bar, what's wrong with me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. can you tell me an alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made these changes to the code and then it worked well.

**CSS**:

```css
DIV.list_item_container {
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0px;
}
DIV.image {
    width:90px;
    height: 90px;
    float: left;
}
DIV.description {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: gray;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
#name-list {
    width: 300px;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name-list').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Searchuser",
                data: {
                    searchText: request.term,
                    maxResults: 10
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.DisplayName,
                            avatar: item.PicLocation,
                            rep: item.Reputation,
                            selectedId: item.UserUniqueid
                        };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {

            alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);

            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var inner_html = '<a><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img src="' + item.avatar + '"></div><div class="label"><h3> Reputation:  ' + item.rep + '</h3></div><div class="description">' + item.label + '</div></div></a><hr/>';
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append(inner_html)
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```